# Magento dataflow import file issue

Tags: magento-1.7, import

Can anyone please provide me with a dataflow import .CSV file format where I can import multiple images and also add associated products to configurable products.

I have .CSV file but there how i upload multiple images and add associated products ? 
I don't want to upload manually one-by-one.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: use the export dataflow to export a test configurable product with images, then analyse it, you'll see what Magento needs for import ;)

Comment: Instead of asking the community to re-describe what's already documented, please take a look at Magmi's wiki. Its documentation has everything you can possibly do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The basic import tool is very basic and has its limits. To do so, you can use Magmi or create your own importer script. We have our own to do so for a catalog of clothes.

Comment: Hello Christophe,                               Thanks for reply                                    I have downloaded magmi zip file, In this zip file have some folders like cli, conf, engines, inc etc.. Now please navigate me what i have to do with these folders. Mean where i keeps these folders? At root? And how to operate with it?                         Thanks

Comment: You have all the needed information here : http://mindyourownwebsite.com.au/magento-installing-magmi-to-bulk-import-products/